# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist even path is set

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have system path set to chromedriver and giving correct path in code. I am trying to run test where just launch the chrome browser from Android Studio. TI shows error..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist
```

Chrome 56 version and chromedriver 2.27 version. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on Windows, you may try with older chromedriver. I had similar issue with same chromedriver/Chrome versions as yours on Windows 10. Lowering chromedriver version to 2.25 fixed it.

Comment: I am actually using mac and android studio to run. Older version didn't help either. thanks!